# What is the recommendation for python class-styles in 2.x, eventually updated to 3.x

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, python-2.7

In python 2.x there is some motion to define classes in the new-style

```
class Foo(object):
```

rather the old-style

```
class Foo:
```

For python 3.x I read that this ambiguity goes away. But I am not sure what this means.

Two questions:

- What is the proper style for class definitions in python 3.x
- What is the recommendation for class definitions for python 2.x code, that will eventually upgraded to python 3.x code

Comment: There is no good reason not to use new-style classes in Python 2, and as for Python 3, that format is backwards-compatible, as all types defined with class automatically inherit from `object`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Python 3 all class are "new-style". Both syntaxes do the same thing in Python 3.x.

---

> What is the proper style for class definitions in python 3.x

```
class Foo:
```

---

> What is the recommendation for class definitions for python 2.x code

In Python 2.x the recommendation is to always use new-style classes when writing new code. This applies regardless of whether you plan to upgrade to Python 3.x or not.

```
class Foo(object):
```

Comment: perfect! No further questions. Thanks.